# Calculating net ventilation

Tags: mathematical-physics

I have the question:

[image]

Here is my attempt is this correct ?

[image]

Comment: Correct except you forgot to account that window only lets 90% of visible light pass.

Comment: Would you like to post an answer then?

Comment: So the final answer is correct then ?

Comment: Just multiply the $Q_1$ you calculated with $0.9Q_1$ and replace the value in total heat flow rest of the procedure is correct.